# An error with the league ranking in Web Apps

Tags: support

Kindly visit this link: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/5/month/webapps and see this screenshot:

[image]

My question is: I have been a User here for only 6 Days, so how did I get a #41 Change in rank for the month? It must be "Not previously Ranked" (as I have in the Week's Rank).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's working to me.

According to [last month's stats](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/5/month/webapps/2012-04-01?sort=reputationchange&page=2), you earned 42 reputation points in April, putting you at #42 for the month. That would be a month-over-month change of +41. This jives with [your reputation graph](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/19533/myselfpoddar?tab=reputation&sort=time) which shows you earning 42 reputation points on April 30, the first day stats are available.